# Export a gridview to Excel with page orientation set to landscape?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, gridview

Haven't found any good solution to export a GridView to Excel with following options :

1. Page orientation set to Landscape
2. Margins Normal
3. All columns fit to one page

Existing code to export to Excel is as follows

```
private void ExportToExcel(GridView grdGridView)
    {
        DataTable dt = Whatever();             
        grdGridView.AllowPaging = false;
        grdGridView.Columns[13].Visible = false;
        grdGridView.DataSource = dt;
        grdGridView.DataBind();
        string attachment = "attachment; filename=ExcelSheet1.xls";
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
        Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);         
        HtmlForm frm = new HtmlForm();                        // Create a form to contain the grid
        grdGridView.Parent.Controls.Add(frm);
        frm.Attributes["runat"] = "server";
        frm.Controls.Add(grdGridView);
        frm.RenderControl(htw);
        Response.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.End();
        }
}
```

What could be the best possible way to export to Excel in order to achieve all of this? Do I need to use some library or some other tool like report viewer? Is it possible or not?

Comment: Can you share your research so far?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found the solution

Download epplus library.

```
using OfficeOpenXml;

   private void ExportToExcel()
    {

        using (ExcelPackage objExcelPackage = new ExcelPackage())
        {

                //Create the worksheet    
                ExcelWorksheet objWorksheet = objExcelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("ExcelSheet1");

            DataTable dtQuoteComparison = dt   //Load the datatable into the sheet, starting from cell A1. Print the column names on row 1    
            objWorksheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dt, true);


            var start = objWorksheet.Dimension.Start;
            var end = objWorksheet.Dimension.End;
            for (int row = start.Row+1; row <= end.Row; row++) //iterate through rows
            {                    
               objWorksheet.Cells[rowStart, colStart, rowEnd,colEnd].WhateverProperty=value; 
            }
            objWorksheet.PrinterSettings.Orientation = eOrientation.Landscape;
            objWorksheet.PrinterSettings.FitToWidth = 1;
            //Write it back to the client    
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(filepath))
                System.IO.File.Delete(filepath);

            //Create excel file on physical disk    
            FileStream objFileStrm = System.IO.File.Create(filepath);
            objFileStrm.Close();

            //Write content to excel file    
            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filepath,objExcelPackage.GetAsByteArray());
        }
    }
```

Now the problem I am facing is that All columns fit to one page is not working even after setting

```
 objWorksheet.PrinterSettings.FitToWidth = 1;
```